# Maximization and Derivatives

Tags: derivatives, optimization

How would I derive the profit max function in terms of $y$?

The equation is $$py - (1-s)(C(y)+\alpha)$$

I know $d/dy$ for $py$ is $p$. However, how would I derive equation for the latter term?
I know $C(y)$ would turn to $C'(y)$.

Comment: Assuming first order condition is sufficient to get profit maximizing level of $y$ (not "profit max function for $y$", which I do not know what is), $y^{*}$ say, you have $p-(1-s)C'(y^{*})=0$.

Comment: Thank you. Why does (1-s) not get derived?

Comment: Because from the way you wrote this is seems like $s$ is a parameter. If it is not, then your question should have said so.